# Opening a system tray program with python

Tags: python, windows, automation, system, ctypes

I have a program which when minimized, disappears into the system tray (the sub-process which runs the gui closes and only the parent process is running in the background)

I want to, using python, open this program from the system tray.

To do this manually, you would have to go to the system tray, click it, and double click the icon - this "activates" the gui and shows the program onscreen (kind of like what anti-virus softwares do).

Is there a way to do this with ctypes/pygetwindow (I can't use pywin32) other packages could work - due to security reason not all packages are available to me so the best solution would be using the simplest and most popular packages available